# Error Markers Maps

Tags: php, html, sql, google-maps

I'm trying to create a Google Maps map that shows info (location of the deposit and weight of the material deposited). It only shows one markers instead of multiple. I think the problem is the atribution of data to the variable $users_dump_map but I don't have the knowledge to repair the problem. What should I do?

PHP

```
<?php
        $db_name = 'db.db';
        $db_drvr = 'sqlite';

        $user_info = Array();
        $user_dumps = Array();
        $containers = Array();
        $users_dumps_map = Array();

        try{
            $pdo = new PDO("$db_drvr:$db_name");
            $ui_query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = :user_id');
            $ui_query->bindParam(':user_id', $_POST['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $ui_query->execute();
            $user_info = $ui_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $ud_query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM garbage WHERE user_id = :user_id');
            $ud_query->bindParam(':user_id', $_POST['user_id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
            $ud_query->execute();
            $user_dumps = $ud_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            $c_query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM containers');
            $c_query->execute();
            $c_results = $c_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            foreach( $c_results as $dump ){
                $containers[$dump['id']] = $dump['location'];
                $users_dumps_map[$dump['id']] = $dump['coord'];
            }


        }
        catch(PDOException $e){
            var_dump($e);
            $user_info = Array();
            $user_dumps = Array();
            $users_dumps_map = Array();
        } 
    ?>
```

GOOGLE MAPS MAP

```
echo' <script>
                function myMap() {
                    var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng('.$users_dumps_map[$dump['container_id']].');
                    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById("map");
                    var mapOptions = {
                        center: myCenter,
                        zoom: 5
                    };
                    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: myCenter
                    });
                    marker.setMap(map);

                    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        content: "'.$dump['quantity'].'"
                    });
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }

            </script>';
```

asfasdf

Comment: Can you give us an example data `$users_dumps_map`?

Comment: Coordenates. Imagine 40.1243, -8.8282

Comment: @KhoaTruongDinh Man, Plz Help Me On This One. I'm stuck in this for days... Im so frustrated.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/parth1020/4481893